# how to parsing of xml in mosync ide

Tags: c++

i am sending a request to server and receive an response as an form of xml but i want to parse it so which method i should prefer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "How to parse XML" just use something simple as [eXpat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) (SAX parser) or plug into something more sophisticated like [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) (SAX & DOM parser) or libxml2.

From your headline it seems you are using mosync, which already provides XML parsing http://www.mosync.com/documentation/tutorials/processing-xml

If your question is "How to choose between SAX and DOM parsing" just read the wikipedia articles on SAX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML , stating benefits and drawbacks. It basically comes down to "SAX requires less resources but DOM might be easier to use".

Otherwise please describe your problem in more detail.